# Delete only field in elasticsearch using elastic4s

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic4s

I want to delete only one particular field and value in elasticsearch using elastic4s library. However, all I see everywhere is different mechanisms to delete the whole document. Can anyone help? is this supported?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an update script to remove a field when you're doing an update, eg

```
"script" : "ctx._source.remove(\"name_of_field\")" }'
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue with following command in elatic4s (version 6.5.1):

```
client.execute { deleteByQuery("myindex", "mytype", matchQuery("key", "valuexy")) }
```

this deletes documents containing entries with "key -> valuexy".